# Encountering errors using Python Selenium's expected_conditions (EC) for iCloud login automation. Difficulty finding iframe elements and sending keys

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have tried to automatically write login and password icloud.com

Right now I am succesfull click Sign In button.
Next I switch to iframe. But can't find element for send.keys(write login, password)

Always have error like this - TypeError: WebDriver.find_element() takes from 1 to 3 positional arguments but 6 were given
If I try to find element By.ID or CLASS_NAME without WebDriverWait - Always error can't find element

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFdmz.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3eO8x.png)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome
driver.get("https://www.icloud.com")
btn_log_in = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "sign-in-button")
btn_log_in.click()


iframe = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='home-login-component']//iframe[@id='aid-auth-widget-iFrame']")
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)


sign_in = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element(By.XPATH, "//span[@id=' apple_id_field_label']"))
sign_in.send_keys('12345678')
```

Help please, I can't find my mistake 2 days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have three separate issues causing this to fail.

1. You have a typo in your `xpath` lookup, simply remove the leading white space
2. You are calling `EC.text_to_be_present_in_element` incorrectly.
3. You cannot call `send_keys()` on `sign_in` as it is a `boolean`

Addressing all of the above fixes the issue and inserts text into the box

```
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.icloud.com")
btn_log_in = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "sign-in-button")
btn_log_in.click()


iframe = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='home-login-component']//iframe[@id='aid-auth-widget-iFrame']")
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

#Remove typo, push your locator into a tuple and pass 'Apple ID' as the text to find
sign_in = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.XPATH, "//span[@id='apple_id_field_label']"), 'Apple ID'))

#Correctly user ActionChains to send_keys
ActionChains(driver).send_keys("abc").perform()
```

Comment: It's work! Thanks.
But now I have one more problem. I can't fill up password field. 
Process finished with exit code 0, but don't fill up passowrd

Comment: @telemen7 Make sure the field is the active target before you send_keys, or it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, I have code like this.
Process finished with exit code 0
But don't fill up password field

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

o = Options()
o.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=o)
driver.get("https://www.icloud.com")
btn_log_in = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "sign-in-button")
btn_log_in.click()


iframe = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='home-login-component']//iframe[@id='aid-auth-widget-iFrame']")
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

sign_in = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.XPATH, "//span[@id='apple_id_field_label']"), 'Apple ID'))
ActionChains(driver).send_keys("abc12345").perform()

btn_sign_in = driver.find_element(By.ID, "sign-in")
btn_sign_in.click()

input_pass = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.XPATH, "//span[@id='password_field_label']"), 'Password'))
ActionChains(driver).send_keys("12345").perform()
```